# document.body.childNodes.item table

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have this simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="nod">item node name</p>
<button onclick="stats()">get name</button>
</body>
<script>
function stats(){
    var x = document.getElementById("nod");
    x.innerHTML = document.body.childNodes.item(0).nodeName;
}
</script>
</html>
```

when i ask for 1st(0) nodeName i get #text and 2nd is p 
when the

element is after body like  with no line brake in code 
i get 1st p why this brake in code matters?

Comment: Cause you have a textnode between the body and the paragraph, and textnodes are nodes too.

Comment: Instead of looking at childNodes you should go for children property.